# Reference elements in matrices in Julia while assigning values in other matrices

Tags: matlab, julia

I have a vector X whose elements are zeros and ones. I want to create another vector Z of the same size as X where each element of Z is 0 if the corresponding element in X is zero, otherwise it is a random draw from a. uniform distribution. In Matlab I can easily do this by:

```
n = 1000;
X = randi([0, 1], [1, n]);
Z(X) = rand(); #Here wherever X takes a value of 1, the element of Z is a draw from a uniform distribution.
```

I want to implement this in Julia. Is there a cleaner way of doing this instead of using if conditionals. Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
julia> n = 1000;

julia> x = rand(Bool, n);

julia> z = zeros(n);

julia> using Distributions

julia> z[x] .= rand.(Uniform(-10, 10));

julia> z
100-element Vector{Float64}:
 -2.6946644136672004
  0.0
  0.0
  ⋮
```

You can adjust the parameters of the `Uniform` distribution to what you need, or leave that argument out if the default `[0, 1)` range is what you need.

The line `z[x] .= rand.(Uniform(-10, 10))` uses Julia's logical indexing (same as MATLAB) and broadcasting features - for every `x` value that is `true`, the `rand` call is made and the result assigned to that element of `z`.

The advantage of using the broadcast (compared to creating `rand(Uniform(-10, 10), count(x))` and assigning that to `z[x]` for eg.) is that the values are directly assigned in-place to their destination in `z`, and so there's no extra unnecessary memory allocated (as mentioned by @DNF in the comments).

Comment: You can avoid an unnecessary allocation of a vector on the right hand side by using broadcasting: `z[x] .= rand.(Uniform(-10, 10))`

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your Matlab code doesn't work in Matlab, for *two* reasons: Firstly because logical indices must be boolean, they cannot be 0 and 1. And secondly, because `Z(X) = rand()` will draw only a single random number and assign it to all the corresponding elements of `Z`.

Instead, you may want something like this Matlab code:

```
X = rand(1, n) > 0.5
Z(X) = rand(sum(X), 1)
```

In Julia you could do

```
X = rand(Bool, n)
Z = float.(X) # you have to initialize Z
Z[X] .= rand.()
```

**Edit:** Here's an alternative with a comprehension, where you don't need to initialize `Z`:

```
X = rand(Bool, n)
Z = [x ? float(x) : rand() for x in X]
```

Answer (score 0):

Technically, what you are sampling from here is a left-censored uniform distribution -- equivalent to the mixture of a Dirac distibution at 0 and `Uniform(0, 1)`.  [The next release of Distributions.jl](https://juliastats.org/Distributions.jl/dev/censored/) will have an implementation for `censored`, which will remove the need to do any fancy assignment at all:

```
Z = rand(censored(Uniform(-1.0, 1.0), lower=0.0), N)
```

where the extent to the left is chosen so that the mixture components have equal weight.